# What expression can I use in Watson Assistant for opening times on certain dates?

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I have a Watson bot i'm trying to program for reserving tables. I'd like to know the expression I could use to implement my opening times.

For example the restaurant has the following hours:

Monday-Friday 11:30AM until 10:30PM, last reservation can is 9:30PM.
Saturday-Sunday 5PM until 10:30PM

I don't want Watson to take reservations outside those hours. How code I implement this in slots?

Comment: please mention a code you tried, SO isn't discussion platform. Good question generates a fair amount of opinion requirement, but some questions are primarily opinion-based.

Answer (score 1):

You can use methods of the [expession language](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/assistant?topic=assistant-dialog-methods) to evaluate the input.

For example a condition to check if it is a valid weekday reservation could be :

```
@sys-date.reformatDateTime('u')<6 AND @sys-time.before('21:30:01') AND @sys-time.after('11:29:59')
```

I would not recommend to to do the check in slots.
Easier would be to do the check after slot-filling. 
If it is no valid reservation you can offer the client to just try again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any way to do this in Watson Assistant directly. You can do conditional evaluation (check if a number if greater than or less than another number), but your needs are a little more complex (with time involved, and even dates too).

I'd suggest handling your reservation validation process externally using the webhook feature. Collect your reservation date and time, and then send those to your webhook as parameters. The webhook can then respond with a confirmation that the reservation is OK, or it could reject it (and provide a reason). When your dialog node that calls the webhook gets the response, if it sees a rejection based on operating hours, it could inform the user that they need to select a time that the restaurant is open, remind them of the hours, and then go back to the node that collects the reservation info.